# Linux/Debian based application won't compile

Tags: linux, matlab, debian, simulink, dvb

My question is related to my grade project. Its about mobile video transmission using DVB-H link layer. Its a comprehensive project itself, and there are separate parts. I mainly construct system in Matlab Simulink, but there is one part, responsible for encapsulation/decapsulation of the stream packet, which was designed in Linux environment.

I didn't want to install new OS just for one application, so I run Linux on VMware Player as a virtual machine. So here is my problem - the applications (for encapsulation and decapsulation) won't compile (install) completely. I see mainly missing library problems. I tried to install necessary libraries, but the original application still couldn't see some of them. I feel like I'm missing something small, but clear to rather experienced Linux user. Here is the link to the programs
http://sp.cs.tut.fi/mobile3dtv/download/ 
"DECAPS - DVB-H Decapsulator Software" is the one (and FATCAPS link is there).

I couldn't find alternative encapsulator/decapsulator in for Windows environment. Its my last and only choice. If please some of the Linux users could try to run them in Linux environment, maybe its because I'm using virtual machine? Its also noted that the application was designed for Debian based systems, but I also did install Debian as a virtual machine and application won't even configure. Please help, guys, I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to install the development versions of the libraries -- under Debian, the'll be named the same as the original package, but with a "-dev" suffix.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I don't recall seeing that option, there's just the option of picking the package type, i.e .tar, .zip etc. I was expecting some sort of install file and then convenient application, with GUI, interface, like in Windows. But there just libraries, libraries...

Comment: Sounds like you're installing the libraries the hard way: from the original source rather than through the Debian package manager.  In that case, you may need to manually point the compiler at the libraries through "configure" options or compiler flags.

Comment: Yes, I download externally every missing library and then install independently. I didn't know about Debian package manager, I'll research that. I don't want to bother much, but could you please try to run one of them on your machine?

Comment: It looks like you need to install the "liblog4c" package in addition to the ones listed in the Readme file.  This may be what's causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, I'll try to apply your advices.